# It's possible to exchange data from two different clients with two differents sockets (one server) INDEPENDENTLY?

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming, client-server

I tried to make this but didn't work out. Because, the code on the server has an order and if there is a "listen" to a client 1, for example, the client 2 will just make the connection after client 2. Besides, after the two connections established successfully, the order of "read" functions also interferes on the data exchange. I mean, if there is a "read" function for client 1 before a "read" function for client 2, you can only receive the data from client 2 if you had already received from client 1 first. How do I manage the receive data from both clients whenever I want?

Comment: Just about all books and tutorials on sockets should tell you how to use sockets *asynchronously*. Usually it's handled by polling using the `select` (or similar) function.

Comment: If you use sockets *synchronously*, you usually need to spawn a separate thread to handle each client independently. If you use sockets *asynchronously*, you can use `select()` or `(e)poll()` to poll for activity on multiple sockets at a time, or on Windows you can use Overlapped I/O or I/O Completion Ports.